# When I try to play my Music Discord Bot it doesn't play music

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

When I try to play my Music Discord Bot it doesn't play music. It uses ytdl-core and ffmpeg
My code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client

const ytdl = require("ytdl-core")


const token = 'API TOKEN'

const PREFIX = '?';

var version = '1.2';

var servers = {};

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!' + version);
})

bot.on('message', message => {
    
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'play':

            function play(connection, message){
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}))

                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                    if(server.queue[0]){
                        play(connection, message);
                    }else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                });



            }



            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send("You need to provide a link!")
                return;
            }

            if(!message.member.voice.channel){
               message.channel.send("You must be in a Voice Channel to play the bot!")
               return;
            }

            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voice) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            })

        break;
    }



    });
    
    
    bot.login(token);
```

Whenever I try to play a song this error happens:

> (node:5180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: FFmpeg/avconv not
> found!
> at Function.getInfo (C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:130:11)
> at Function.create (C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:143:38)
> at new FFmpeg (C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:44:27)
> at AudioPlayer.playUnknown (C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js:47:20)
> at VoiceConnection.play (C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\util\PlayInterface.js:71:28)
> at play (C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\index.js:29:48)
> at C:\Users\picar\Desktop\DiscordMusicBot\index.js:66:17
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> (node:5180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled
> promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`
> (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)
> (node:5180) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
> not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
> code

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed FFmpeg ? Or ffmpeg-static ?

Try doing `npm i ffmpeg ffmpeg-static`, it should update everything, let us know if it changes anything !

Also try to install `npm i @discordjs/opus` since it is required to play audio in Discord :)